# Autowire Spring XML bean inside Spring JavaConfig

Tags: spring, javabeans, xmlbeans, spring-java-config

I have a xml bean definition and JavaConfig bean definition in the same project. The JavaConfig need to reference the XML bean. But When i autowire the xml bean definition inside JavaConfig I get NoSuchBean definition error. My question is: Isnt the xml beans and JavaConfig beans visible to each other? If not how do i inject the xml bean into JavaConfig? Thanks

Edit:

Changing @Autowire to @Resource fixed it, but i dont understand why. Autowire should go after type and the XML bean is of the type Autowire is annoted with.

Comment: Without seeing your config and your exception, we can only guess.

Answer (score 1):

If your bean is not being picked up by Autowire, you need to ensure the configuration file for the beans is being read and in turn is generating the beans.

One easy way to check is if you are using an IDE with Bean detection capability to see if the IDE is picking up the bean.

If this is working then please paste in your code of the xml with bean in it and xml containg your scan ability.